# Swagger not picking methods with empty value

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, swagger

I am using swagger to document my rest apis.

An example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc/api/fruit", produces = "application/json")
@Controller
@Api(value = "Fruit", description = "api for fruits", produces =  "application/json")
public class FruitResource {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "")
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "Resource to get fruits", produces = "application/json", notes = "get fruits", response=Fruit.class)
public ResponseEntity<Fruit> getFruits() throws Exception {
    return new ResponseEntity<Fruit>(someServiceCallToGetFruits(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

As seen above, the `value` in `RequestMapping` above the method is empty ("").

Because of this, this class and the method is not getting picked up by swagger.

But when I change the RequestMapping line above method to as below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
```

It starts working.

Is this a bug ? How can I make swagger to work with `""` path values. I do not want to put `"/"` above all such methods.

Comment: Have you tried to not specify the empty value? Like `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` or `@GetMapping()`?

Comment: Is the `@RequestMapping` here, a spring annotation? Also when it works with value="/", what is the complete path displayed on swagger?

Comment: @AlekseiBudiak: That worked.. thanks!!

Comment: @Nik glad it helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to explicitly specify empty value if you don't want to add extend the API path for the particular method. Instead, the following annotation could be used:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Or even

```
@GetMapping()
```